# Increase just by one when a key is pressed

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to increase the variable "shot_pressed" just by one when the key "s" is pressed no matter how long I pressed. But the result is that the variable keeps on increasing. The longer I pressed, the bigger the value of the variable. Below is a part of my code.

```
import keyboard

shot_pressed = 0

if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
    shot_pressed += 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all looks like you use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard

Second, I assume your code is not like you wrote above but like

```
import keyboard

shot_pressed = 0

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        shot_pressed += 1
        print("shot_pressed %d times"%shot_pressed)
```

If yes, here is the core of the problem: is_pressed will be always True, while key is pressed. So `if` condition will be True and `while` will repeat it many times.

There are two ways of dealing with that.

1) Use the same method, but check if this is the first is_pressed moment, so inroduce `was_pressed` variable:

```
import keyboard

shot_pressed = 0
was_pressed = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        if not was_pressed:
            shot_pressed += 1
            print("shot_pressed %d times"%shot_pressed)
            was_pressed = True
    else:
        was_pressed = False
```

2) Better use the library. You can set a hook, so on key pressed your function will be called (only once for one press). So the code will look like this:

```
import keyboard

shot_pressed = 0

def on_press_reaction(event):
    global shot_pressed
    if event.name == 's':
        shot_pressed += 1
        print("shot_pressed %d times"%shot_pressed)

keyboard.on_press(on_press_reaction)

while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that *keyboard* module but the problem with your code is that the program takes input once. Your program should wait next input from keyboard. Try to use `while` loop to take inputs from user.

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard 
import time 
shot_pressed = 0 
try: 
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("S"):
            shot_pressed += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print(sh)
except Exception as er:
    pass
```

Or can use read key

```
try:
    shot_pressed = 0 
    while True:
        key.read_key()
        if key.is_pressed("s"):
            sh += 1
            print(shot_pressed)
except Exception as er:
    pass
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the answer, why a sleep is needed etc..

Also, you forgot a print

Comment: Do you sleep for loob delay                                                                                    Because when you press the letter "s" while the verb is running quickly and the value of the variable will be increased rapidly so that it reaches 1000 in one pressure

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that module, but you probably want the same thing that you would want in javascript.  keyboard.KEY_DOWN instead of is_pressed.

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.KEY_DOWN

You probably need to handle things asynchronously as well.

Comment: just as a note, because most keyboard drivers (windows and linux alike, not sure about macOS) send multiple `press` and `release` events when a key is held, this won't make any difference unless you disable that behavior (can be done on linux at least)