# Why doesn't Python random like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am starting out with Python and thought to make a dice roller for fun.
I have created this:

```
import random
import keyboard
print("Which dice would you like? 6 side or 20 side?")
dice = input()
print("Press the space key to initiate a roll")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(' '):
        print(random.randint(0, dice))
```

Now I go by the assumption that making a random in the range of 0 and a pre-made variable (which has a number in it, not null) should work. I mean, it works in Java and C# so why not here right?

For some reason tho Python hates this, I debugged it and it dies at the print line and gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiril/PycharmProjects/Practice/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(random.randint(0, dice))
  File "C:\Python\lib\random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

What's the problem here? Does it not accept pre-made variables (I mean the random class)? Is it maybe that the input in Python makes everything String (I don't know if it's true but hey maybe, only second day on this language)?
How do I fix this?

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You need to convert it with `int()`. Searching for the dup....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the input returned from `input` is `str`
just do:

```
dice = int(input())
```

Comment: Oooh I see, thanks, tho now another thing.
After I hit space, instead of doing the random 1 time it does it indefinitely.
How do I make it so it only gives me a number once?

Comment: @MrBoomBastic try using is_released instead of is_pressed, let me know if it worked.
Otherwise, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184374/increase-just-by-one-when-a-key-is-pressed

Comment: apparently, is_released does not exist for me lol

Comment: Found a better way:
```
while True:
    keyboard.wait(' ')
    print(random.randint(1, dice))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input function return a `string` type value. You need to convert it into `int` type value.
For this:

```
dice = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

dice = int(input()) to convert input to int

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this `dice=int(input())`

Here is the code

```
import random
import keyboard
print("Which dice would you like? 6 side or 20 side?")
dice =int(input())
print("Press the space key to initiate a roll")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(' '):
        print(random.randint(0, dice))
```

Try it,it will work